# I am connecting a Dual CD/MP3 Receiver in my boat if I connect the red to positive, do I connect the ground wire to the negative side

Tags: ground

I am installing a radio in a fiberglass boat. The instructions call for red o positive and black to ground. Can I use the negative post as the ground

Comment: All 0V references are called “ground”

Answer (score 1):

Yes - on a boat (and in many other situations) the negative terminal of the battery or power source is considered "Ground".